# Nginx silently dropping header lines that exceed 1128 bytes

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have Nginx set up as a reverse proxy to a uWSGI application (a Django app). Due to the nature of the content that the Django app is hosting, sometimes the URLs get long. Really long. Because of this, the `Referer` HTTP header can also sometimes get long.

Here's the problem. Nginx drops the `Referer` received from the client if it exceeds 1128 bytes (discovered by trial and error). Anything 1128 bytes or smaller gets passed to the upstream server. Everything larger gets dropped. This is a problem because Django's CSRF protection mechanism requires an intact `Referer`.

Here's the relevant section of my Nginx config. file:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header Referer           $http_referer;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I looked through the Nginx documentation and couldn't find a setting that controlled the maximum length for client headers. Frustrated, I even began pouring over the source code for Nginx, which didn't turn anything useful up either.

What do I need to do to get Nginx to pass `Referer` unmodified to the upstream server?

#### Version Information

- Ubuntu 14.04 Server 64-bit
- nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- uWSGI 1.9.17.1-debian
- Django 1.7.0

Comment: Sounds like you've run into a bug. What versions of everything are you running?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Xavier's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/638912/30745) and the ensuing discussion led me to the real cause of this issue: uWSGI. It appears that uWSGI was stripping the header:

```
[WARNING] unable to add HTTP_REFERER
```

The solution was painfully simple - when launching uWSGI, I needed to simply include the following option:

```
--buffer-size 8192
```

All of the headers make it through to Django now and CSRF verification succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx header read size is controlled by two directives :

- `client_header_buffer_size [buffer_size]` which is the default buffer that would fit in most cases
- `large_client_header_buffers [count] [buffer_size]` which are additionnal buffers allocated on demand if it doesn't fit in `client_header_buffer_size` buffer. You must tailor this last directive to your case and make sure than `buffer_size` is greater than any line passed in the request (headers + URL with HTTP method and HTTP version).

Comment: I've set `client_header_buffer_size 16386;` and `large_client_header_buffers 4 16386;` but neither seems to make a difference even though the total length of the request is less than 4096 bytes.

Comment: @NathanOsman something in the logs in debug mode ? Do you get a 400/431 status code ?

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden status code - which I believe comes from the upstream server. The 403 is triggered by Django because it can't verify the contents of the `Referer` header.

Comment: @NathanOsman Did a quick test with a dummy proxy, nothing of this kind happened. Could you post the full configuration, your curl request and response to nginx, the intermediate curl request and response to your upstream target and your logs in debug mode ?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to get all of the information together.

Comment: Here's a cURL request that triggers the error: https://dpaste.de/5FrB. Interestingly, if I remove the query string from the URL, I no longer get the same error. (Just a failed CSRF check instead of a complaint about the `Referer` being missing.) Perhaps I was wrong. The error may be related to the length of the query string in the URL. I'll continue to dig deeper.

Comment: @NathanOsman Does the response headers contain something from the upstream ? I hardly doubt nginx is in cause here.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Running uWSGI with verbose logging reveals that it is indeed the culprit: "[WARNING] unable to add HTTP_REFERER".